# Can a class use methods declared in one of its categories?

Tags: objective-c, class, methods, categories, large-files

I have a big class. To sum up, it has only one method that other classes should call and then a bunch of methods to do different stuff, depending on the type of data received. The .m file is getting so large that I want to split it up. My idea is to divide the methods among different categories (each category will work with a specific type of data). And so I did.

Inside of the main method I didn't change anything, so lines such as

```
[self methodNowInMyCategory];
```

are still there. However, I now get warnings in my class's main file since "instance method -methodNowInMyCatefory not found". The main .h file is importing the .h files of the categories, so the methods are visible (Xcode colors the code). The class just does not recognize them as its own.

Is there a way to, in a class, use a method declared in one of its categories? If not, which approach would you recommend me to solve my problem? The main method receives a file path, opens the file, analyzes the content and then sends it one or more methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can split your category declarations into one or more .h files, and then import the category headers in your class's main .m.

Comment: Maybe I did not explain mayself correctly in the question. 

Each of the categories I created has its own .h and .m files. All .h files are already included in the main class. =/

Comment: Aha! Rereading your answer i got it: " import [...] in your class's main **.m**". That made the trick =) Thanks!

Comment: @Solem: The reason you need to import in the .m file is because your category headers import the class's header, so importing them from the class's header creates a circular dependency, which generally leads to "method not found" errors.

Comment: @Chuck, I thought that "importing" solving that problem. Moreover, my header files start with a #ifndef to make sure they are included only once and avoid problems. You must be right, however, because after moving the imports to the .m the problem solved. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @Solem: Both `#import` and include-guards solve a related but different problem where including multiple files that all include one common file (or each other) will create duplicate definitions. `#import` only includes the file the first time, but this uniquing doesn't solve the problem of circular dependencies, where each file needs the contents of the other file to go before it. Since only one can go before the other without duplication, the code in one of the files will fail to see the code in the other.